# Is a diagonal matrix times a matrix A a linear combination of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say there is a set of m $\mathbb R^n$ vectors, represented as matrix $A$ in $\mathbb R^{r*m}$; and an m-by-n diagonal matrix $D =diag(i_1, i_2,...,i_m)$.

Is $D$ times $A$ a linear combination of that set of vectors? Is $0A$ the trivial linear combination?

**edit** OK, I realized I'm definately wrong, since a diagonal matrix is quadratic. But consider a matrix m-by-n, with $\lambda_n$ real numbers in each row on the matching columns.

Comment: $m$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are not a vector space.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood so many things, but I'm just beginning with linear algebra. I mean set of vectors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have $n$ column vectors $\textbf{v}_{1}, \textbf{v}_{2}, \ldots \textbf{v}_{n}$, each from $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, you can write this as an $m \times n$ matrix $A$.

$$A = \left( \begin{array}{c} \textbf{v}_{1} | \textbf{v}_{2} | \cdots|\textbf{v}_{n} \end{array} \right).$$

Now let $\textbf{c}$ be an $n\times 1$ column vector whose entries are constants $c_{1}, c_{2},\ldots,c_{n}$, i.e.
$$\textbf{c} = \left( \begin{array}{c} c_{1} \\ c_{2} \\ c_{3} \\ \vdots \\ c_{n} \end{array} \right)$$
then 
$$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}c_{i}\textbf{v}_{i} = A\textbf{c}.$$

Comment: I'll edit in more detail if it's necessary, but you should first try to make sense of this yourself - perhaps write out the matrix A in full, i.e. in terms of the elements of the vectors and do the matrix multiplication to see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I was looking for!

Comment: It makes sense to me, but I'm going try it with actual numbers, because actual numbers are always clearer than abstract formulas. That's the only way form me to memorize formulas, and their use cases. I can do matrix multiplication, I've learnt to do it 'mechanically'.